# Using c# how to receive value of a select statment (SQL)

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

I want to retrieve the resulting value of a select statement into a string variable. Actually i did successful login coding but after that i want redirect page according to their roles from retrieving to the database, if that is ADMIN then it goes to the ADMIN HOME PAGE and if this is USER then it goes to the USER HOME PAGE. below my code is there check out where i am wrong.

```
protected void btn_lpc_Login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        string strCon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sessionname"].ConnectionString;
        string strSelect = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM LOGIN_DETAILS WHERE EMAIL_ID=@EMAIL_ID AND PASSWORD =@PASSWORD";

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strCon);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = strSelect;

    SqlParameter username = new SqlParameter("@EMAIL_ID", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 36);
    username.Value = tbx_lpc_username.Text.Trim().ToString();
    cmd.Parameters.Add(username);

    SqlParameter password = new SqlParameter("@PASSWORD", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
    password.Value = tbx_lpc_password.Text.Trim().ToString();
    cmd.Parameters.Add(password);

    con.Open();
    int result = (Int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

here on words my doubt :

```
    if (result >= 1)
    {
        string strSelect2 = "SELECT ROLEID FROM LOGIN_DETAILS WHERE EMAIL_ID=@EMAIL_ID";

        if (srole == "USER")
        {
            Session.Add("usnm", tbx_lpc_username.Text);
            Response.Redirect("~/ADMIN_PAGES/LPC_ADM_HomePage.aspx");
        }
        else if (srole == "ADMIN")
        {
            Session.Add("usnm", tbx_lpc_username.Text);
            Response.Redirect("~/ADMIN_PAGES/LPC_ADM_SettingsPage.aspx");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "validation", "<script language='javascript'>alert('Invalid Username and Password')</script>");
    }
   }
```

Comment: You should probably execute the second query (the one in the strSelect2 variable)

Answer (score 0):

```
    string strSelect2 = "SELECT ROLEID FROM LOGIN_DETAILS WHERE EMAIL_ID=@EMAIL_ID";
    cmd.CommandText = strSelect2;
    username = new SqlParameter("@EMAIL_ID", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 36);
    username.Value = tbx_lpc_username.Text.Trim().ToString();
    cmd.Parameters.Add(username);


    int roleId = (Int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

    if (roleId == 2) //USER
        {
            Session.Add("usnm", tbx_lpc_username.Text);
            Response.Redirect("~/ADMIN_PAGES/LPC_ADM_HomePage.aspx");
        }
        else if (roleId == 1) // ADMIN
        {
            Session.Add("usnm", tbx_lpc_username.Text);
            Response.Redirect("~/ADMIN_PAGES/LPC_ADM_SettingsPage.aspx");
        }
```

Comment: may i know the solution of my questions... i think this is not my question's answer ..